# What is the difference between a Case Report and a Brief Report?

Tags: terminology, publications

What exactly is the difference between a **Case Report** and a **Brief Report** in the [New England Journal of Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_England_Journal_of_Medicine)?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**
In NEJM, case reports are called brief reports.

**Background**
A [case report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_report) is in general a report on a single subject/patient. It is a broadly used term in many journals. From the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_report):

> [A] case report is a detailed report of the symptoms, signs, diagnosis, treatment, and follow-up of an individual patient. Case reports may contain a demographic profile of the patient, but usually describe an unusual or novel occurrence.

The NEJM in specific does not feature an article layout for case reports in particular; instead, they have devised a common outline for those papers that either report on one case (case reports), or on a bunch of related cases, or of one specific family. From the [Author's instructions of NEJM](http://www.nejm.org/page/author-center/article-types):

> **CLINICAL CASES**
>   Brief Reports usually describe one to three patients or a single family.

Hence, in the NEJM, a 'case report' is one of the article outlines under the header 'brief report'.